# .NET stream classes equivalent in Cocoa or CoreFoundation?

Tags: cocoa, iostream, core-foundation

I used `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`, `TextWriter`, `BinaryWriter` and so on classes on *.NET*. They were so useful. And in Cocoa, I can't find similar classes. There're only basic streams and some classes. I can make some similar classes myself, but I want to know is there pre-implemented classes or not before making new one.

Can you let me know about stream related classes on Cocoa or CoreFoundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream classes for Core Foundation are [CFReadStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001440) and [CFWriteStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html)- see [CFNetwork Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFStreamTasks/CFStreamTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH6-SW1). Their Cocoa counterparts are [NSInputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInputStream) and [NSOutputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOutputStream)- see [Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188i)

Their functionality is extremely basic (for example, you can't seek in read/input streams) so I've found that their functionality is limited.  They are suited for use with `CFNetwork`, but  other than that I have rolled my own when the need arose.  Not being familiar with .NET it sounds like the classes you reference are almost Java-like adapters, which unfortunately these aren't.

Comment: I wanted simple text reader from stream. Maybe with delegate in Cocoa. OK thanks!

Comment: You can always try using a combination of `NSData` and `NSString`.